# regex to match alphanumeric and hyphen only, strip everything else in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to strip everything except alphanumeric and hyphens.

so far i've got this but its not working:

```
String = String.replace(/^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+$/ig,'');
```

any help appreciated?

Comment: How is it not working?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to remove everything except alphanum, hypen and underscore, then negate the character class, like this

```
String = String.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9-_]+/ig,'');
```

Also, `^` and `$` [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) should not be there.

Apart from that, you have already covered both uppercase and lowercase characters in the character class itself, so `i` flag is not needed. So, RegEx becomes

```
String = String.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9-_]+/g,'');
```

There is a special character class, which matches `a-zA-Z0-9_`, `\w`. You can make use of it like this

```
String = String.replace(/[^\w-]+/g,'');
```

Since `\w` doesn't cover `-`, we included that separately.

Quoting from [MDN RegExp documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#character-classes),

> #### \w
>
> Matches any alphanumeric character from the basic Latin alphabet, including the underscore. Equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.
>
> For example, `/\w/` matches `'a'` in `"apple,"` `'5'` in `"$5.28,"` and `'3'` in `"3D."`

Comment: :) you can remove the `/i` flag as well, while you're at it